# Identify first unique value when multiple conditions are met using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe representing a two-year daily time series of temperature for two rivers. I have identified when the temperature is either above or below the peak temperature. I have also created a run-length ID column for when temperature is either above or below a threshold temperature of 10 degrees.

How can I get the first day of year for each site and year and the following conditions:

1. maximum run-length & below peak = `TRUE`
2. maximum run-length & above peak = `TRUE`

Example Data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(dataRetrieval)

siteNumber <- c("01432805","01388000") # United States Geological Survey site numbers
parameterCd <- "00010" # temperature
statCd <- "00003" # mean
startDate <- "1996-01-01"
endDate <- "1997-12-31"

dat <- readNWISdv(siteNumber, parameterCd, startDate, endDate, statCd=statCd) # obtains the timeseries from the USGS
dat <- dat[,c(2:4)]
colnames(dat)[3] <- "temperature"

# To view at the time series
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = Date, y = temperature)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~site_no)
```

To create the columns described above

```
dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(year = year(Date),
         doy = yday(Date)) %>% # doy = day of year
  group_by(site_no, year) %>%
  mutate(lt_10 = temperature <= 10,
         peak_doy = doy[which.max(temperature)],
         below_peak = doy < peak_doy,
         after_peak = doy > peak_doy,
         run = data.table::rleid(lt_10))
View(dat)
```

The ideal output would look as follows:

```
   site_no year doy_below doy_after
1 01388000 1996       111       317
2 01388000 1997       112       312
3 01432805 1996       137       315
4 01432805 1997       130       294
```

`doy_after` = the first row for `after_peak == TRUE` & `max(run)` when `group_by(site_no,year)`

`doy_below` = the first row for `below_peak == TRUE` & `max(run)` when `group_by(site_no,year)`

- For `site_no` = 01388000 in `year` = 1996, the `max(run)` when `below_peak == TRUE` is 4. The first row when`run` = 4 and `below_peak == TRUE` corresponds with date `1996-04-20` which has a `doy` = 111.

Comment: No, I am trying to find `doy_above`, I suspect it could be found using `summarise()`

Comment: Noted, `above_peak` typo has been fixed to `after_peak`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the data is already grouped, just `summarise` by extracting the 'doy' where the `run` is `max` for the subset of `run` where the values are TRUE in 'below_peak' or 'after_peak' and get the `first` element of 'doy'

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
 summarise(doy_below = first(doy[run == max(run[below_peak])]), 
           doy_above = first(doy[run == max(run[after_peak])]), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  site_no   year doy_below doy_above
  <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 01388000  1996       111       317
2 01388000  1997       112       312
3 01432805  1996       137       315
4 01432805  1997       130       294
```